# Smbclient protocol negotiation failed

Tags: kali-linux, smbclient

Im trying to transfer a file using samba. I started a smbserver and can not connect to it.

Command:
`smbclient -L //ip address/temp`

Error:
`protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED`

Answer (score 24):

In last release of Kali there is an issue I encountered too. In order to get `smbclient`to work you need to edit the SMB configuration file. And then at least mine worked.

I'm using `vi` to I edit the config file as follows:

```
vi /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

You need to add the following settings under `GLOBAL`:

```
client min protocol = CORE
client max protocol = SMB3
```

Comment: This helped me with my error: `protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED` on arch linux. Only upon adding the two lines, I was prompted for a password for the first time (and could log on).

Comment: Can confirm this is also an issue in openSUSE Leap 15.2, and that adding these two lines immediately fixed the problem. However, upon [some further reading](https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/leap/reference/html/book.opensuse.reference/cha-samba.html#sec-samba-client-inst), this enables the obsolete SMB1 protocol which decreases security for this part of the system.

Comment: confirm: ubuntu server and router comtrend. It does not worked via parameters: -m SMB3, etc.

Comment: Works also on Ubuntu 20.04.03 LTS desktop and Speedport Pro Plus router (Telekom germany)

Comment: Confirmed solution on Parrot OS 5.3 Electro Ara (arm64)